# Display Featured Image

Tags: loop, post-thumbnails, genesis-theme-framework

I am having some issues trying to get featured image to appear on my front page.

I am using Genesis, then genesis child theme. I only want the featured image to appear on my  `front-page.php`. I know I need to write a custom loop in order for the featured image to appear only. However I am having trouble completing it.I am not sure what code to write into my custom loop.

I did this:

```
/** Code for custom loop */
function my_custom_loop() {

}

/** Replace the standard loop with our custom loop */
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'my_custom_loop' );
```

Comment: This should be posted on the StudioPress Forums

Answer (score 0):

Displaying the featured image (referred to as 'thumbnail' in Wordpress functions) should not require you to replace your page loop.  I'm not a Genesis user so there's a chance that is the case.

Displaying a feature image for the page is as simple as using the `the_post_thumbnail` function. Here is the [Codex Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) for full details.

Simply use this where you want an image to be displayed in your page template:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Comment: -1 Answering off topic questions

Answer (score 0):

Like @jdm2112, I'm not a Gensis user, but here is an alternative method to retrieving the featured image. I use this method because it offers more functionality to altering the featured image (ie: thumbnail size).

You can add these functions to your functions.php file.

```
public function get_featured_image_id() {
    return (int) $this->get_meta( '_thumbnail_id' );
}

/**
 * Get the featured image url for the given featured image id
 *
 * @param string $size
 * @return string|false
 */
public function get_featured_image_url( $size = 'full' ) {

    $attachment_id = $this->get_featured_image_id();
    if ( ! $attachment_id ) {
        return false;
    }
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
    if ( ! $src ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $src[0];
}

/**
 * Get the HTML for the featured image html
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function get_featured_image_html( $size = 'full' ) {

    if ( $featured_image_id = $this->get_featured_image_id() ) {
        return wp_get_attachment_image( $featured_image_id, $size, '' );
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Use case in your WordPress "The Loop"

```
echo esc_url( $post->get_featured_image_url( the_id() ) );
```

Comment: stoopkid1 and jdm2112, I will try this once I get home.Thanks.

Comment: -1 Answering off topic questions